# Kafka, Unable to produce and consume events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

While trying to set kafka on 2 replica and 1 master boxes, got a weird condition where I was not able to consume or produce to a topic.

Using **Mirror Maker** to sync data between **replica <--> Master**. Getting following logs unending :

> [2016-08-26 14:28:33,897] WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2016-08-26
> 14:28:43,515] WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2016-08-26 14:28:45,118]
> WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2016-08-26 14:28:46,721]
> WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2016-08-26 14:28:48,324]
> WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2016-08-26 14:28:49,927]
> WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2016-08-26 14:28:53,029]
> WARN Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 disconnected
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)**

Only way I could recover was by restarting Kafka which produced this kind of logs :

> [2016-08-26 14:30:54,856] WARN Found a corrupted index file, /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-43/00000000000000000000.index,
> deleting and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log) [2016-08-26
> 14:30:54,856] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 0 in log
> __consumer_offsets-43. (kafka.log.Log) [2016-08-26 14:30:54,857] INFO Completed load of log __consumer_offsets-43 with log end offset 0
> (kafka.log.Log) [2016-08-26 14:30:54,860] WARN Found a corrupted index
> file,
> /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-26/00000000000000000000.index,
> deleting and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log) [2016-08-26
> 14:30:54,860] INFO Recovering unflushed segment 0 in log
> __consumer_offsets-26. (kafka.log.Log) [2016-08-26 14:30:54,861] INFO Completed load of log __consumer_offsets-26 with log end offset 0
> (kafka.log.Log) [2016-08-26 14:30:54,864] WARN Found a corrupted index
> file,
> /tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-35/00000000000000000000.index,
> deleting and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)**
>
> ERROR Error when sending message to topic dr_ubr_analytics_limits with key: null, value: 1 bytes with error:
> (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update
> metadata after 60000 ms.**

This is my test phase so I was able to restart and recover from the master box but I want know what caused this issue and how can it be avoided. Is there a way to debug this issue?

Trying to achieve following via Kafka

[image: Trying to achieve following]

Comment: It looks like either: something went wrong with the broker, or lack of connectivity between broker and MM. Do you have logs from the broker prior to the restart?

Comment: I think too that it would have occurred because of connectivity issue as I have been killing the process rather than shutting down the process gracefully. But I want to make sure, this is does not happen in the production and there is a way to recover the state.?
Yeah I have the logs, what specifically I should be searching for?

Comment: MirrorMaker2 or Confluent "Cluster Linking" simplifies this model, by the way. In any case, corrupt logs are definitely because unclean process termination, and you definitely shouldn't be doing that in production. Also, if your MirrorMaker logs say "localhost", you've got a replication loop, which is not shown in your diagram